# Connect Jenkins with Git/Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, msbuild, nunit

I'm trying to connect Jenkins and Github and I know that there is a lot of stuff you can find using the internet, but I couldn't fix my problem.

### My current situtation

I learning how to write Unit Tests with NUnit 3.4. The whole time I had like 3 Steps.

**1.)** I write my C#-Project with unit tests

**2.)** In the same folder where my Solution is, I have a msbuild-file which build my project and creates stuff like:

- Console-Report.xml
- MyProject.dll
- MyProject.pdb
- MyProject_Test.dll
- MyProject_Test.pdb
- nunit.framework.dll
- nunit.framewirk.xml

**3.)** I use Jenkins (nunit- und msbuildPlugins are installed): Every time I press "Build now" it calls my msbuild-file in the project folder:

[image]

So far, so good.

### What I want

Now I want Jenkins to build every time I change and update my code and I read that there are many ways to do that. I want to try it with Github/Git.

**1.)** I created a new repository "CannonAttack" and imported my project "MyCannonAttack"

**2a.)** I copied and pasted the web URL(Used HTTPS), but Jenkins shows me an error: 
[image]

**2b.)** I also tried it with Git and a local repository, like in this [link](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/getting-started-with-jenkins-git-and.html), but I get also an error. 
[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it: I opened services.msc, found jenkins and changed the login-settings(Admin rights)